# Why does display:inline-block prevent printing across multiple pages?

Tags: javascript, css, printing

I have a web page that has two `<table>` elements floated next to each other.

Recently I did some upgrades and instead of floating them I styled them as `display:inline-block` as this fits better to the page.

Often times, users print this page using `ctrl-p` and it usually prints off about 5 pages long.

Now, since I styled these two elements as `display:inline-block`, the printing cuts off after one page.

When I change the elements back to floating or no `display` set, it prints fine all 5 pages.

Is there any way around this?

**Note:** I am not using any fancy printing plug-in - just simply the window default `print()` method.

Comment: try adding an empty div after your table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use print @media.

```css
@media print {
 /* THIS CSS ONLY WILL BE EXECUTED FOR PRINTING, USE YOUR FLOAT HERE /*
}
```

Comment: Duh.... Yeah, I figured this out shortly after I posted the question. But thank you!

Comment: =D <3 was a pleasure.